# DRY: C++11 enum class vs C enum

Tags: c++, c++17, dry, enum-class

I have class like this:

```
struct InsertResult{
    enum class Status{
        INSERTED            ,
        UPDATED_IN_PLACE    ,
        REPLACED            ,
        SKIP_INSERTED       ,
        ERROR_NO_MEMORY     ,
        ERROR_INVALID       ,
        ERROR
    };

    bool        ok;
    Status      status;
    // more members here...

    // spill the enum:
    constexpr static auto INSERTED          =  Status::INSERTED         ;
    constexpr static auto UPDATED_IN_PLACE  =  Status::UPDATED_IN_PLACE ;
    constexpr static auto REPLACED          =  Status::REPLACED         ;
    constexpr static auto SKIP_INSERTED     =  Status::SKIP_INSERTED    ;
    constexpr static auto ERROR_NO_MEMORY   =  Status::ERROR_NO_MEMORY  ;
    constexpr static auto ERROR_INVALID     =  Status::ERROR_INVALID    ;
    constexpr static auto ERROR             =  Status::ERROR            ;
}
```

the idea of constexpr static members is to avoid double typing, e.g.

```
if (insert() == InsertResult::INSERTED){
//  OK...
}
```

vs

```
if (insert() == InsertResult::Status::INSERTED){
//  OK...
}
```

Any easy way to make it "better" without using `C enum`?

Comment: In other words, you want stronger typing without introducing a new scope?

Comment: Enumerations are as much C++ as C. Why do you want to avoid (specifically) "C enum"?

Comment: This would be solved well in C++20 with `using enum Status;`

Comment: @Artyer and until C++20? No way?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *'easy'* – if you want to define all those members at one single place without having to repeat code in constants then this could be achieved via an X-macro – result, though, will be a not too nice to read enum definition. Still might be worth the effort if you have many members and many changes – and I really mean *many*...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++20 you would do `using enum Status;`.

Pre-C++20 the best idea I have is writing a macro to generate your constexpr variables for you. The example below uses [`macro_sequence_for`](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for), a little library I made to simplify preprocessor loops.

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Chttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for/master/include/macro_sequence_for.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+MAKE_ENUM(name_,+members_)+%5C%0A++++enum+class+name_+%7BSF_FOR_EACH(BODY_ENUM_ELEM,+SF_NULL,+SF_NULL,,+members_)%7D%3B%5C%0A++++SF_FOR_EACH(BODY_VAR,+SF_STATE,+SF_NULL,+name_,+members_)%0A%0A%23define+BODY_ENUM_ELEM(n,+d,+x)+x,%0A%23define+BODY_VAR(n,+d,+x)+%5B%5Bmaybe_unused%5D%5D+static+constexpr+d+x+%3D+d::x%3B%0A%0A%0AMAKE_ENUM(+E,%0A++++(e1)%0A++++(e2)%0A++++(e3)%0A)%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:100,l:%274%27,m:32.1702130840982,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+17.0.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:29.489361993756685,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:pp,i:(clang-format:%270%27,editorid:1,filter-headers:%270%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,treeid:0),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Preprocessor+Output+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:38.34042492214513,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <macro_sequence_for.h>

#define MAKE_ENUM(name_, members_) \
    enum class name_ {SF_FOR_EACH(BODY_ENUM_ELEM, SF_NULL, SF_NULL,, members_)};\
    SF_FOR_EACH(BODY_VAR, SF_STATE, SF_NULL, name_, members_)

#define BODY_ENUM_ELEM(n, d, x) x,
#define BODY_VAR(n, d, x) [[maybe_unused]] static constexpr d x = d::x;
```

Then this:

```
MAKE_ENUM( E,
    (e1)
    (e2)
    (e3)
)
```

Expands to this:

```
enum class E
{
    e1,
    e2,
    e3,
};

[[maybe_unused]] static constexpr E e1 = E::e1;
[[maybe_unused]] static constexpr E e2 = E::e2;
[[maybe_unused]] static constexpr E e3 = E::e3;
```

And here's a longer version that lets you specify the enum constant values:

```
#include <macro_sequence_for.h>

#define MAKE_ENUM(name_, members_) \
    enum class name_ {SF_FOR_EACH(BODY_ENUM_ELEM, SF_NULL, SF_NULL,, members_)};\
    SF_FOR_EACH(BODY_VAR, SF_STATE, SF_NULL, name_, members_)

#define BODY_ENUM_ELEM(n, d, ...) BODY_ENUM_ELEM_SELECT(__VA_ARGS__, BODY_ENUM_ELEM_A, BODY_ENUM_ELEM_B,)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define BODY_ENUM_ELEM_SELECT(x, y, z, ...) z
#define BODY_ENUM_ELEM_A(name_, init_) name_ = init_,
#define BODY_ENUM_ELEM_B(name_) name_,

#define BODY_VAR(n, d, ...) BODY_VAR_(n, d, __VA_ARGS__,)
#define BODY_VAR_(n, d, x, ...) [[maybe_unused]] static constexpr d x = d::x;

MAKE_ENUM( E,
    (e1)
    (e2, 42)
    (e3)
)
```