# Checking emptiness of X macros

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to build a X macro that would allow to generate an enum with a bunch of useful functions like `.toString()` for instance. The version I got can be implemented like this:

```c
#define MAKE_ENUM \
  ENUM_NAME( LanguageId ) \
  ENUM_TYPE( unsigned int ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( English, 0 )\
  ENUM_ENTRY( French ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( German ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( Italian ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( Spanish ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( Polish ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( Korean, 128 ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( ChineseTraditional, 129 ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( ChineseSimplified, 130 ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( Japanese, 131 )
#include "GenericToolbox.MakeEnum.h"
#undef MAKE_ENUM
```

The deploying of the X macro `MAKE_ENUM` is done under the header `GenericToolbox.MakeEnum.h`.

This version works so far as expected. However I want `ENUM_TYPE` to be an optional argument, therefore sometimes it wouldn't be set by the user and the enum would be defined as the default `int`.

For that I need to figure out if the unfolding of the MAKE_ENUM is empty. The version I came up with is such:

```c
#define TEMP_EXPAND(x) x
#define TEMP_SELECT_THIRD(_1,_2,num,...) num
#define TEMP_IS_NOT_EMPTY_IMPL(...) TEMP_EXPAND(TEMP_SELECT_THIRD(__VA_ARGS__,1,0))
#define TEMP_ARGS_DUMMY( ... ) dummy,##__VA_ARGS__
#define TEMP_IS_NOT_EMPTY( val ) TEMP_IS_NOT_EMPTY_IMPL(TEMP_ARGS_DUMMY( val ))

// [...]

#define ENUM_TYPE(type_) type_ // MAKE_ENUM will only return type_ if it exists
#if TEMP_IS_NOT_EMPTY( MAKE_ENUM ) == 1
  typedef MAKE_ENUM EnumType;
#else
  typedef int EnumType;
#endif

// [...]
```

**The issue is that it seems the `TEMP_IS_NOT_EMPTY` macro only works with Clang but not GCC. Do you have any idea why? And would there be a viable workaround?**

To clarify the issue, I've added a test withing the code:

```c
#define MAKE_ENUM_EMPTY
#if TEMP_IS_NOT_EMPTY( MAKE_ENUM_EMPTY ) == 1
// NOT empty
#warning "TEMP_IS_NOT_EMPTY does not work correctly for empty macro"
#else
// empty
#endif

#define MAKE_ENUM_NOT_EMPTY unsigned int
#if TEMP_IS_NOT_EMPTY( MAKE_ENUM_NOT_EMPTY ) == 1
// NOT empty
#else
// empty
#warning "TEMP_IS_NOT_EMPTY does not work correctly for NOT empty macro"
#endif
```

With GCC I get the warning message: `#warning "TEMP_IS_NOT_EMPTY does not work correctly for empty macro"`

Cheers!

Comment: `gcc` always returns that the macro is "not empty", even if the `MAKE_ENUM` does returns an empty value.

Comment: I do not understand the point of this. What should the macros generate? Could you write a simple example what should be the input given presented input? Even if you "want" `ENUM_TYPE( unsigned int )` to be "optional" - what does it mean and what does it affect? You can't "store" information from one macro to another (there are no global variables in preprocessor), I do not follow exactly what is the point of calling it.

Comment: The point is to have a the possibility to use other types for the enum. By default it's an `int` but sometimes I want to explicitly specify that it should be a `size_t` for instance.

Comment: `enum` in C programming language is an enum, it has it's own integral type, you can't change the type of an `enum`. I still do not understand. What is the point of `ENUM_ENTRY` if you just use `typedef int EnumType;` ? Are you sure you want to maintain such code?

Comment: Can't reproduce - works perfectly with all gcc versions available on godbolt: [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/dbvWdn8z3) - what compiler version are you using / can you share a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @nadrino -- with the upcoming C23 spec you can specify the underlying type of an `enum`. GCC 13 already supports this; it doesn't look like Clang supports it yet.

Comment: @KamilCuk `EnumType` is just a definition that I'm going to use mutliple time within the unfolding file. It's here to avoid having to redispatch the `MAKE_ENUM`. The `enum` type is actually specified later like this: `enum MyEnumName : EnumType{`.

@Turtlefight I'm using GCC 9 or 11 depending on the computing cluster.

@adabsurdum Really? I'm not sure I understand what you mean here... My project is actually a C++ one (maybe this is the cause of the issue..!)

Comment: @nadrino -- you said that you wanted to [specify the type of an `enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77792301/checking-emptiness-of-x-macros#comment137145240_77792301). You can do this if you are using a compiler that supports this new feature of C23 (GCC 13 is the only one I know of that is currently supporting it). This lets you do, e.g., `enum lil_enum : char { /* ... */ }`; or `enum big_enum : size_t { /* ... */ };` to specify the underlying type.

Comment: @nadrino -- _"My project is actually a C++ one...."_ Why is this tagged [tag:c] then? I don't understand your goal. C++ has provided the ability to specify the underlying types for enumerators since C++11.

Comment: I tagged it C since it was about macros. I once asked a question about macros by tagging C++ but people were not happy with it. I didn't know the enum definition would differ between the two actually

Comment: @nadrino -- many people are never happy about macros, whatever the language ;) You should tag based on the language that you are using to be sure that you get the most relevant advice. C and C++ are pretty far apart. Since you are using a C++ compiler, maybe you can solve your problem without macros by using [regular C++ enums](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Comment: Honestly, I'd move away from x-macros to normal macros. Writing loops in them isn't hard (e.g. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77522918/2752075)), and you get way nicer syntax (no need to `#include` a magic file to generate a enum, you just call a macro; you can conveniently check for empty arguments with `__VA_OPT__`, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the following design:

```
#define ENUM_NAME  LanguageId
#define ENUM_TYPE  unsigned int
#define ENUM_FIELDS \
  ENUM_ENTRY( English, 0 )\
  ENUM_ENTRY( French ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( German ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( Italian ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( Spanish ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( Polish ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( Korean, 128 ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( ChineseTraditional, 129 ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( ChineseSimplified, 130 ) \
  ENUM_ENTRY( Japanese, 131 )
#include "GenericToolbox.MakeEnum.h"
```

Then:

```
// "GenericToolbox.MakeEnum.h"
#ifndef ENUM_TYPE
// default:
#define ENUM_TYPE int
#endif
typedef ENUM_TYPE ENUM_NAME;
// process ENUM_FIELDS ...
#undef ENUM_TYPE
#undef ENUM_FIELDS
#undef ENUM_NAME
```

Fun fact: this is the design that [STC library](https://github.com/stclib/STC) is using.

Comment: Ah yeah that might be a very simple solution. I'll try it out and see if all my secondary features work like this.

Comment: I confirm this was the way to go. Much easier to implement and maintain! https://github.com/nadrino/cpp-generic-toolbox/blob/main/include/GenericToolbox.MakeEnum.h

Comment: Checking if a variadic macro is entirely empty is actually easy, using this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417186/is-this-a-valid-way-of-checking-if-a-variadic-macro-argument-list-is-empty

Answer (score 1):

A more "pure" form of X macros would contain any item in the list and then you can decide whether to use that item or not when creating the macro passed to the X macro list.

Full example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static_assert(__STDC_VERSION__ >= 202311L ||   // C23 or later?
              __STDC_VERSION__ == 202000L,     // C2x placeholder?
              "Nah, no C23 for you.");

#define LANG_ENUM_LIST(X) \
 /* name     value  */    \
  X(English,  0 )         \
  X(Korean, 128 )         \

typedef unsigned int lang_enum_int_t;

typedef enum : lang_enum_int_t  // C23 enum
{
  #define ENUM_ITEM(name, value) name = value,
  LANG_ENUM_LIST(ENUM_ITEM)

  LANG_ENUM_N
} lang_enum_t;

int main (void)
{
  printf("%d\n", English);
  printf("%d\n", Korean);

  // verify that C23 enum is working as expected:
  puts(_Generic(English, int: "int", unsigned int: "unsigned int"));
}
```

- This doesn't mess things up by including the enum type in the macro - what's the point of doing that?
- Also this requires an explicit integer value for every enumeration item, but only because `#define ENUM_ITEM(name, value) name = value,` was defined that way. We could as well swap it for:

  ```
    #define ENUM_ITEM(name, value) name,
  ```

  And then default enumeration from 0 and upwards will be used.
- And finally, if we subscribe to the "Keep It Complicated, Stupid" paradigm, we may mess around with C23 `__VA_OPT__`, mainly serving the purpose of showing off in-depth but rather useless C knowledge, rather than adding anything of concrete value to the program design:

  ```c
  // NOT RECOMMENDED

  #define LANG_ENUM_LIST(X) \
    /* name     value  */    \
     X(English,  0 )         \
     X(French)               \
     X(Korean, 128 )         \
      ...

    #define ENUM_ITEM(name, ...) name __VA_OPT__(=) __VA_ARGS__,
  ```

  And now English is 0 (explicit), French is 1 (implicit) and Korean is still 128 (explicit). This is ISO C23, unlike `##__VA_ARGS__`, which is non-standard GNU language and shouldn't be used.