# Can GCC be configured to allow the use of C enums in .s/.inc assembly source files

Tags: c, gcc

I'm working on C project where I have a large amount of code in pseudo-assembly defined in .s and .inc files that needs to reference header files containing enums. These various enums are extremely large and because assembly files can't read actual enums they end up defining hundreds of lines of pseudo-enums that are just

```
#define SOME_ENUM_CONSTANT 168
#define SOME_ENUM_CONSTANT_FOO 169
#define SOME_ENUM_CONSTANT_BAR 170
#define SOME_ENUM_CONSTANT_BAZ 171
```

this is extremely tedious and makes the rest of my C code that also needs to read these enums worse too. Is there some sort of make configuration or weird macro hacks I can use to allow standard enums to be readable by the assembly preprocessor?

I've tried just defining an enum, which results in "error bad instruction 'enum {'". I've also tried various shenanigans with `__COUNTER__`, but that just seems to result in `__COUNTER__` getting inserted literally rather than expanding to a single constant which is then inserted as needed.

Comment: No, it is not possible. You need to write the program which will convert enums into #defines

Comment: So you're saying that you have *existing* C `enum` declarations, and you want to use the enum constant names from those in your assembly sources, with the same values?

Comment: what is code in "pseudo assembly"?

Comment: I was thinking that clang-tidy could help you, but unfortunately it does the opposite - coverts defines to enums :(

Comment: You want x-macros (often written as a .def file); this will require that the enum explicitly specify all values (and doesn't rely on autonumbering), but does not need a dedicated codegen script. Note that the file extension is .S not .s when preprocessor is needed.

Comment: Specific assemblers often have some manner of macro support too. Maybe finding out about that is the best solution for you.

Comment: @o11c "this will require that the enum explicitly specify all values" Not necessarily, there are obscure tricks for making an X macro list "variadic", see the bottom of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77801535/584518. That one requires a C23 compiler however.

Answer (score 1):

For similar issues (in the past), I've used a "metaprogramming" generation script to parse the `enum` declarations and generate a list of `#define` (or `equ`, etc.).

This is run (e.g.) from the `Makefile` *before* processing any `.s` files.

---

Here is the generation [perl] script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# enum2asm -- convert enum to #define

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;

    argparse(0,\@argv,["O"]);
    $opt_O //= "asmenum";

    while (@argv > 0) {
        my($file) = argparse(1,\@argv,["O","T"]);
        last unless (defined($file));
        dofile($file);
    }
}

sub dofile
{
    my($ifile) = @_;
    my($ofile);
    my($inenum);
    local($xfsrc,$xfdst);
    my($buf);
    local(@oline);

    zprtx("dofile: %s\n",$ifile);

    system("mkdir -p $opt_O")
        unless (-d $opt_O);

    open($xfsrc,"<$ifile") or
        sysfault("dofile: unable to open '%s' -- $!\n",$ifile);

    $ofile = "$opt_O/$ifile";

    $tmp_c = "$opt_O/tmp.c";
    $tmp_x = "$opt_O/tmp";
    open($xfdst,">$tmp_c") or
        sysfault("dofile: unable to open '%s' -- $!\n",$tmp_c);

    outf("#include <stdio.h>\n");

    while ($buf = <$xfsrc>) {
        chomp($buf);
        zprtx("dofile: LINE/%d buf='%s'\n",$inenum,$buf);

        outf("%s\n",$buf);

        if ($inenum) {
            if ($buf =~ /^[}]/) {
                $inenum = 0;
                next;
            }
            parseline($buf);
            next;
        }

        if ($buf =~ /^\s*enum/) {
            $inenum = 1;
            next;
        }
    }

    close($xfsrc);

    outf("int main(void)\n");
    outf("{\n");
    foreach $oline (@oline) {
        outf("\t%s\n",$oline);
    }
    outf("\treturn 0;\n");
    outf("}\n");
    close($xfdst);

    system("cc -o $tmp_x $tmp_c");
    system("$tmp_x > $ofile");
}

sub parseline
{
    my($buf) = @_;

    $buf =~ s/^\s+//;
    $buf =~ s/\s+$//;

    $buf =~ s/,$//;

    my(@tok) = split(",",$buf);

    foreach $buf (@tok) {
        $buf =~ s/^\s+//;
        $buf =~ s/\s+$//;
        my(@sym) = split(" ",$buf);
        my($sym) = shift(@sym);
        my($oline) = sprintf("printf(\"#define $sym %%d\\n\",$sym);");
        push(@oline,$oline);
    }
}

sub outf
{
    printf($xfdst @_);
}

sub sysfault
{
    printf(STDERR @_);
    exit(1);
}

sub zprtx
{
    printf(STDERR @_);
}

sub argparse
{
    my($shf,$argv,$opts) = @_;

    if ($shf) {
        return shift(@$argv);
    }
}
```

---

Here is a sample *input* `.h` file:

```
// xxx.h

#include <signal.h>

enum foo {
    GAR = 37,
    BAR, CAR, PAR = 62, BARGE,
};

enum {
    BLUDGER = BARGE + 1,
    FLUDGER, KILO, MILLI, BACKSORT
};

enum mysigs {
    MYSIG_SIGTERM = SIGTERM, MYSIG_SIGINT = SIGINT
};
```

---

When we run the script (e.g. `./enum2asm xxx.h`), the output directory will be `asmenum`

It will get a `asmenum/tmp.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// xxx.h

#include <signal.h>

enum foo {
    GAR = 37,
    BAR, CAR, PAR = 62, BARGE,
};

enum {
    BLUDGER = BARGE + 1,
    FLUDGER, KILO, MILLI, BACKSORT
};

enum mysigs {
    MYSIG_SIGTERM = SIGTERM, MYSIG_SIGINT = SIGINT
};
int main(void)
{
    printf("#define GAR %d\n",GAR);
    printf("#define BAR %d\n",BAR);
    printf("#define CAR %d\n",CAR);
    printf("#define PAR %d\n",PAR);
    printf("#define BARGE %d\n",BARGE);
    printf("#define BLUDGER %d\n",BLUDGER);
    printf("#define FLUDGER %d\n",FLUDGER);
    printf("#define KILO %d\n",KILO);
    printf("#define MILLI %d\n",MILLI);
    printf("#define BACKSORT %d\n",BACKSORT);
    printf("#define MYSIG_SIGTERM %d\n",MYSIG_SIGTERM);
    printf("#define MYSIG_SIGINT %d\n",MYSIG_SIGINT);
    return 0;
}
```

---

The script will compile the `tmp.c` file.

The script will run the generated C executable and send the output to the *corresponding* `asmenum/xxx.h` file:

```
#define GAR 37
#define BAR 38
#define CAR 39
#define PAR 62
#define BARGE 63
#define BLUDGER 64
#define FLUDGER 65
#define KILO 66
#define MILLI 67
#define BACKSORT 68
#define MYSIG_SIGTERM 15
#define MYSIG_SIGINT 2
```

---

The script can be modified via command line arguments to generate different output formats. I included *skeleton* support for this, but didn't actually implement it.

Of course, the script can be modified to put the output files anywhere, with an arbitrary output suffix (e.g. `xxx.inc`) and do (e.g.) `FOO EQU 5` instead of `#define FOO 5` (if desired).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't completely tedious:

```
$ cat e.c
enum {
    Fred = 7, Barney, Wilma
};

int x[] = {
    Fred, Barney, Wilma
};
$ gcc -g -c e.c
$ objdump -g e.o | grep -A1 '(DW_TAG_enumerator)'
 <2><2b>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_enumerator)
    <2c>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x2b): Fred
    <30>   DW_AT_const_value : 7
 <2><31>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_enumerator)
    <32>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x24): Barney
    <36>   DW_AT_const_value : 8
 <2><37>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_enumerator)
    <38>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x30): Wilma
    <3c>   DW_AT_const_value : 9
....
```

So the information is in the object file.   From this you are only a couple of lines of awk from generating a *.h* for your assembly source.

Comment: So he will need to manually create arrays with potentially thousands of values? How is it going to help him?

Comment: The concept of meeting 90%  is an important one as it is a typical point of decreasing returns.   If I really had a problem with this, I could choose to generate my enums from say a ".t" file:   `Fred 7\nBarney\nWilma`; then awk this .t into a .h (`enum { Fred = 7, Barney, Wilma };`), and a .c (`#include ".h"\nint _[] = { Fred, Barney, Wilma };`) and thus it is automated.  Or an endless wait for some maintainer to think "oh yeah".

Comment: But it is not OPs case. He has plenty of enums and needs to convert them to the #defines. How your concepts can help him?